# Detect UIButton order?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

In the app I'm currently working on, I need to drag and drop UIButtons. 
This is working without problem.
The issue I'm facing is that I would like to somehow recognize their orders.
For exemple on my Storyboard, I have in the view those three buttons tagged with numbers :

|2|                 |3|                    |1|

I would like to be able to tell the user whether or not the buttons are in the good order.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Many thanks in advance ;)

Comment: if you know how it's the best and you already use the tag attribute of the buttons, where is now the problem / question? ^^ please specify a bit more ;)

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you wan to check order horizontally. Whenever you want to check the order, just get the `button.frame.origin.x` for all buttons and compare them.
I consider that correct order is `1 | 2 |3`. Call below method whenever you want to check the order :

```
- (void)checkOrder {
    positionOfbutton1 = button1.frame.origin.x;
    positionOfbutton2 = button2.frame.origin.x;
    positionOfbutton3 = button3.frame.origin.x;

    if (positionOfbutton1 > positionOfbutton2 || positionOfbutton2 > positionOfbutton3)
    {
        // Show alert that buttons are disordered
    }
}
```